# PHP Cli key event listener function

Tags: php, command-line

I am making **php cli** application in which I need **Key Event** listener

let's say this is my code
Task To do

```
for($i=0;$i<=n;$i++){
    $message->send($user[$i]);
}
```

Once I'm done with sending messages, I will have to keep connection alive with following code to receive delivery receipts.

I use `$command = fopen ("php://stdin","r");` to receive user commands.

```
while(true){
    $connection->refresh();
}
```

Connection is automatically kept alive during any activities but on idle i have to keep above loop running.

How can I run the event on pressing any key which will make this event break and execute some function?

Comment: You may actually want to look into some queue software. You're not going to have any fun trying to daemonize php natively.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not developed, to handle this kind of problems. The Magic Word would be `Thread`

The Cleanest way, I can Imagine, is taking a look into the Extension [`PThreads`](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads). With it, you can do Threads like in other Language:

```
class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
  public function __construct($arg){
    $this->arg = $arg;
  }

  public function run(){
    if($this->arg){
      printf("Hello %s\n", $this->arg);
    }
  }
}
$thread = new AsyncOperation("World");
if($thread->start())
  $thread->join();
```

The other way would be to do tasks via a queue in a different script. There are some Queue Server out there, but it can be done simple calling `shell_execute` your Queue Script via PHP.exe. On Linux you need something like `...script.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`, Windows `start /B php...`, to stop waiting on Script is finished.